# Do we need both the [children] and [kids] tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, retagging

I noticed that on Bicycles.SE there is both a [children](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) tag and a [kids](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kids) tag. Neither has any usage guidance, and the are not synonyms. I don't see a good reason for there to be both, though, so I think they should be synonyms. I don't have a preference for which is the "main" tag, although the [children](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) has over twice as many questions.

Thoughts?

Comment: [tag:children] is preferable since it's much more likely to be the word that a non-native English speaker would use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good idea - I can't think of a situation where one tag would apply and the other would not.

I'll wait for a day or two before doing, in case someone has other thoughts/comments.

---

This has been completed.   FYI the full list of synonoms is at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms for browsing.